# PHP else condition not working

Tags: php, if-statement

I am stuck with some code.

It's quite simple, I have the following code:

```
 if ($somevariable == 1) {
   echo 'Do Something here';
} else {
   echo 'Do Something Else';                
}
```

$somevariable is returning either 1 or nothing at all.

When the first condition is true ...when it's 1 it's working as it should ...

BUT the else condition does not return "Do Something Else" when nothing is return or it's empty.

Shouldn't ELSE mean any other condition?

How can I sort this problem out?

---

```
UPDATE
```

---

Actual Code:

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `follows` WHERE `user_id` = '$session_user_id' AND `venue_id` = '$venue_id'");

while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
$following = $row2['following'];

if ($following == 1) {
echo 'do something';
} else {

echo 'do something else';

}



}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Why not just use `isset()` instead?

Comment: What is the type on $somevariable? Is it an integer?

Comment: Is that the actual code? it may be that you have used = instead of == and that will always return true so else will never run.

Comment: Do you start with `$somevariable = 1`? If yes, did you double check the variable that overrides the `1`?

Comment: do a `var_dump($somevariable)` right before the if(). Remember that php will typecast MANY things to '1' and evaluate it all to true, even for things you wouldn't expect to do so.

Comment: If `$somevariable` might not be set, you'll need `if (isset($somevariable) && $somevariable == 1)`

Comment: 1 is loosy, meaning it can be either the integer representation of 1, or the value of true

Comment: Yes the 1 is an integer. Also, when it's not 1 var_dump returns nothing at all on the variable.

Comment: check out http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Please post your actual code, and see my answer below. I think that the if statement is not the problem.

Comment: Ok, so if the field "following" is empty, it will be the default value as set in the database. What is that set to? Also, what is the type of the column in the database named "following"?

Comment: I the database the default value is 0 (int)

Comment: If that is the case, your code should work. Try echoing out `$row2['following']` inside the `while` loop. The output should be a series of zeros and ones. Let me know if that is or isn't the case. This will help us understand what's going on.
     `echo "Following: " . $row2['following'] . "\n";`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (isset($somevariable) && $somevariable === 1) {
   echo 'Do Something here';
} else {
   echo 'Do Something Else';                
}
```

This will check if the variable is set and also if it is strictly equal to `1` both in *value* and in *type* (integer).

**Edit: I've tried your code and it seems to work fine. I recommend that you post your actual code. I don't think that the problem is with your if statement.**

Comment: Or from the definition Satch3000 gave of what $somevariable contains try if (!empty($somevariable))

Answer (score 4):

> How can I sort this problem out?

By finding and correcting typo-like errors.

Your code will ALWAYS echo something. So, there are only 2 possibilities

- if it always echoing `'here'` - $somevariable always contains non-empty value. Or in the real code you are running there is **single** `=`, not `==` as you posted
- if it prints nothing - **you are running the code without else part**:

  ```
  if ($somevariable == 1) {
      echo 'Do Something here';
  }
  ```

So, here goes an algorithm for solving all such problems

1. Trust your eyes.
2. Check the code
3. Check the code again.

Comment: I just comment for eye part I was doing  code with without order I just put variable with no echo before know why because else I thought it echo Here is the code .
 `If ($err[0]>0 )  echo $err[0].' '.$err[1];  else  $pln1." $";`

Answer (score -1):

Try to Echo out the value and see what the database returns. What is the actual value? did you see the database?

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `follows` WHERE `user_id` = '$session_user_id' AND `venue_id` = '$venue_id'");

while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
$following = $row2['following'](int);

echo $following;
if ($following == 1) {
echo 'do something';
} else {

echo 'do something else';

}



}
```

PHP has different functions which can be used to test the value of a variable. Three useful functions for this are isset(), empty() and is_null(). All these function return a boolean value. If these functions are not used in correct way they can cause unexpected results.

isset() and empty() are often viewed as functions that are opposite, however this is not always true. In this post I will explain the differences between these functions.

isset()

From PHP Manual:

isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

In other words, it returns true only when the variable is not null.

empty()
From PHP Manual:
empty — Determine whether a variable is empty

In other words, it will return true if the variable is an empty string, false, array(), NULL, “0?, 0, and an unset variable.

is_null()
From PHP Manual:
is_null — Finds whether a variable is NULL

Check out more here

https://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/

Comment: While I won't `-1`, `isset` will only check that the variable is **set** not **empty**.. You should use `!empty` instead.